# Automatically turn on Gmail Vacation Responder from gCal 'Out of Office' events

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, automation

I see some [good scripts on turning on responder](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90075/any-way-to-send-gmail-auto-response-at-certain-times-every-week/107104#107104?newreg=95cdc6da79e743ba9d772b0f31802aeb) for 'every Friday', etc., but with the new gCal feature of 'Out of Office' events, is there a way to turn on vacation responder any time there is currently an OOO event happening on your calendar?

Comment: In theory, you would want a script that is triggered to run at least once daily. This script would get all of the events in your calendar for that day, loop through them, identify OOO events, then using the GMail advance service create a new VacationSettings object. Certainly possible.

Comment: Yeah, sounds about right. Any takers??

Comment: "turn on vacation responder any time there is currently an OOO event happening" - specific to the 'any time' bit, because there's no way to watch for this event you would need to poll for this very often, every 10 minutes perhaps.