# Why does this Google Apps script for Gmail not do anything?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the following script from [Any way to send Gmail auto-response at certain times every week?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90075/any-way-to-send-gmail-auto-response-at-certain-times-every-week/107104#107104). It does not send the expected email.

```
function autoReply() {
var interval = 5;    //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();

    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      if (threads[i].isUnread()){
      threads[i].reply("I am out of office. We will get back to you shortly.");
      threads[i].markRead();
      threads[i].markImportant();
      }
    }

}
```

To test the script I sent emails from another address. I've tested many times with clicking run both before and after the emails were received. I don't believe that should make a difference because the script should run again after the specified interval.

The Execution log shows that the script completes immediately after it starts.

Edit: Removed if statement as per @doubleunary answer,

Comment: You are saying that the code completes without calling `threads[i].reply()`. That indicates that the `for` loop is never iterated, which indicates that `threads.length` is zero, which indicates that `GmailApp.search()` returns an empty array, which indicates that there are no messages in your inbox that match the criteria. Use `console.log()` to write debug messages that you can use to inspect `threads.length`, and verify whether the `for` loop gets iterated.

Comment: Besides adding `console.log` statements as was suggested by doubleunary in the previous comment, consider to use the debugger. If you need help to learn to use it, please post a new question.

Comment: Questions should not be edited because a suggestion given as an answer. Doing so will invalidate the answer, instead if you have a follow-up question, please post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `if ([5,6,0].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 1 && hour < 8) || (day == 4 && hour >= 17))`

The function seems designed to only do its thing when it is run on a Friday (`5`), Saturday (`6`) or Sunday (`0`), or on a Monday (`1`) *provided* that the current time is before (`8`), or on a Thursday (`4`) *provided* that the current time is after 5 p.m.

Modify the conditions in the `if` statement to suit your requirements, or remove the `if` altogether to make the function do its thing on any day at any time.

See [Date.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

To avoid issues with timezones, try this pattern:

```
const timezone = 'GMT'; // replace GMT with your real timezone
const dayOfWeek = Utilities.formatDate(date, timezone, 'ddd');
const hour = Utilities.formatDate(date, timezone, 'HH');
if (['Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'].indexOf(dayOfWeek) !== -1
  || (day == 'Mon' && hour < '08')
  || (day == 'Thu' && hour >= '17')) {
  //...
```

You should replace the `'GMT'` bit with your real timezone. See [Joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) for a list of valid timezone names, and [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) for more info on how to format datetime values as text strings.

Comment: Have you considered the effects of the time zone? Under certain circumstances Date methods might return values from an unexpected time zone.

Comment: Edited the answer to include a timezone pattern.

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't make it work. You were right about my intended schedule. I want it to run at all times. So I removed the if statement as per the code change in the question.

Comment: The execution log has always shown a successful completion. I added the time-driven trigger and it now works. I tried to simplify the code by removing the interval, but that led to "trigger not defined" or other issues. Not a big problem but I'd appreciate a suggestion on how to fix it.

I do have a bigger issue. I tried to use HTML in the reply content, but it was sent as text. Is there a way to use HTML?

Comment: Thanks again. My current code is in the question.

Comment: @steveorg If you have a follow-up question it should be posted as a new question.