# Automatic reply with HTML formatted messages using Gmail Apps Script

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

I'm using a script from another thread on here to send out of office replies on my regular days off each week: [Can I set Gmail "out of office" replies for every week recurring?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/79963)

It sends plain text replies as follows:

```
var message = "This is my day off.";
// several lines later....
  threads[i].reply(message);
```

Can anyone tell me how to adapt this so that var message is injecting a HTML formatted reply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can include an HTML message in reply by using the [`reply(body, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#reply(String,Object)) syntax, instead of the `reply(body)` syntax used above. Plain text body must still be provided for those clients who do not render HTML in messages.

The relevant parts are

```
var message = "This is my day off.";
var htmlMessage = "This is <strong>my day off</strong>.";
//  later 
  threads[i].reply(message, {htmlBody: htmlMessage});
```

The complete script becomes

```
function autoReply() {
  var interval = 5;          //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var daysOff = [4,5,6,0];   // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su
  var message = "This is my day off.";
  var htmlMessage = "This is <strong>my day off</strong>.";
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  if (daysOff.indexOf(day) > -1) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      threads[i].reply(message, {htmlBody: htmlMessage});
    }
  }
}
```